follow exchange message coming in from Milestone server
Wanted to ask what the best approach would be to follow a message send attempt from a Milestone Xprotect server to an exchange 2019 server.
I have alerts on Milestone set up that send out to domain recipients, and those messages are received just fine.  but I'm having an issue sending alerts to external contacts or even a exchange contact with external address. The former I think I am seeing as a open relay, which I don't want, so call that fair.  But the later is confusing me.
If I send a message to the exchange contact from my domain email (via outlook), it goes through fine.  if I tell the Milestone server to send a test message to the same contact, it says it completed fine but no message ever comes across.
Figured there should be a way to watch message details as the exchange server is receiving them and figure out where they are getting dropped/held etc.  Only approach I've tried at the moment is to see if the send connector queues reflected anything erroring out or otherwise, but nothing shows up there so far.
Thank you
